# D/ViewRootImpl(28004): MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

This error ocurred  when i try use the textformfield in flutter. Somebody can help me?
bellow follows the error returned:

```
D/ViewRootImpl(28004): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(28004): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl(28004): MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 885) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 885) or=1
```

And there are a example of my TextFormField in my UI code

```
Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: loginController,
              validator: (value){
                if (value.isEmpty){
                  return "Os campos não podem ser vazios";
                }
                return null;
              },
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              focusNode: _emailFocus,
              onFieldSubmitted: (term){
                _fieldFocusChange(BuildContext context, FocusNode currentFocus,FocusNode nextFocus) {
                  currentFocus.unfocus();
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocus);  
                }
                _fieldFocusChange(context, _emailFocus, _nameFocus);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Email",      
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0
                ),      
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color:  Colors.white, width: 1)
                ),
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1)
                )
              ),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              )
            ),
          ),
```

Please, help me

Comment: I have the same issue, I was able to overcome this issue by the changing my state to a Stateful Widget. I don't clearly but the GlobalKey<FormState> makes this error when I use that in the Stateless Widget.